# How to get a non-pop up alert to show up based on a string value in another object in C#/asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

First off here's my code:

```
    private void CheckPolicy(string PolicyNumber, string PolicyMod)
    {   //Check to see if the policy mod combo is a valid policy mod
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn_DataDelivery"].ConnectionString);

        string strPolicyStatus = "";

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Advantage.GetAdvantageEligibilityPolicyCheck";
            SqlParameter inparm1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@PolicyNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            inparm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            inparm1.Value = "%" + PolicyNumber;//Pass a wildcard with the policy Number 

            SqlParameter inparm2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@PolicyMod", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            inparm2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            inparm2.Value = PolicyMod;

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {

                if (rdr["PolicyStatus"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    strPolicyStatus = rdr["PolicyStatus"].ToString();                        

                    switch (strPolicyStatus)
                    {
                        case "Policy Does Not Exist":
                            lblresult.Text = strPolicyStatus.ToString();
                            break;
                        case "Policy Exist":
                            SaveExceptionData(PolicyNumber, PolicyMod, 1, 0, Environment.UserName); //Need to add the user Information
                            break;
                        case "Duplicate Policy":
                            lblresult.Text = strPolicyStatus.ToString();
                            break;
                        default:
                            lblresult.Text = "An error occurred, please try again.";
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                { }
            }                
            rdr.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            lblresult.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    private void SaveExceptionData(string PolicyNumber, string PolicyMod, int AdvantagePolicyIndicator, int isDeleted, string UserName)
    {

        //string Name = Environment.UserName;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn_DataDelivery"].ConnectionString);
        void GetPolicyCheck(ref string strPolicyStatus)
        {
            strPolicyStatus = "";
        }

        bool valb = vala;
        if (valb)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Save Was successful");
        }
        valb = !valb;
        if (!valb)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Policy Exist");
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred, please try again.");
        }
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "advantage.InsertIntoAdvantageEligibilityOverride";
            SqlParameter spPolicyNumber = cmd.Parameters.Add("@PolicyNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            spPolicyNumber.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            spPolicyNumber.Value = PolicyNumber;


            SqlParameter spPolicyMod = cmd.Parameters.Add("@PolicyMod", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            spPolicyMod.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            spPolicyMod.Value = PolicyMod;


            SqlParameter spAdvantagePolicyIndicator = cmd.Parameters.Add("@AdvantagePolicyIndicator", SqlDbType.Int);
            spAdvantagePolicyIndicator.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            spAdvantagePolicyIndicator.Value = AdvantagePolicyIndicator;


            SqlParameter spisDeleted = cmd.Parameters.Add("@isDeleted", SqlDbType.Int);
            spisDeleted.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            spisDeleted.Value = isDeleted;


            SqlParameter spUserName = cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            spUserName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            spUserName.Value = UserName;

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //this was missing.

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Inserted Successfully')", true);
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

I want to get the application to display a text on screen (not in a pop-up is the cause of this whole question) based on what the string value in CheckPolicy's if-case statement is. When the policy is check in CheckPolicy and when the result is "Policy Exist" I want the SaveExceptionData to return "Save Was successful" and if it returns anything besides "Policy Exist" then to return "Save Failed". I believe to do this correctly I need to get the string result in CheckPolicy to be read by SaveExceptionData and use a bool which connects to an if statement that will execute my desired result? Any direction would be appreciated.

Also note, I tried to create a bool that referenced the CheckPolicy result but I couldn't get it to reference in the SaveExceptionData section. Which is what the mess below SaveExceptionData labeled GetPolicyCheck and Bool are.

Comment: if you're wanting no postback - is this MVC or Web Forms? MVC is pretty simple, just create a hook to it so you can grab with JavaScript. Web Forms isn't hard either, you'd be relying on [WebMethod]. Basically, I'd have CheckPolicy return maybe a compound object (a "code" and a string which would go in your label). Then in your page, have it use $.ajax (jQuery) or some other method to call out to CheckPolicy, get the code and/or string back, and act upon it how you'd like.

if you're fine with postback, a lot of this is pretty moot. You can set the lblresult.Text as long as it is accessible.

Comment: I'm so sorry for this late response I was busy with another project. Could you possibly show me how to call a postback? I researched it and understand what it does, but I'm not sure how it would be implemented in my case. Thank you for your time so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I do it, but with your code spliced in where applicable.

Have a class for your return object. Be as granular or as vague as you want it (if you want to return just a message and then on the client set react based on the string, do that, if you prefer a code, do that too. If you want to just return a string, you can do that and bypass creating a special class):

```
public class CheckPolicyMessage
{
  public string Code { get; set; } // could be whatever type you want it to be.
  public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Now at this point, I'd modify CheckPolicy to return this message.

```
[WebMethod]
public CheckPolicyMessage CheckPolicy(string PolicyNumber, string PolicyMod)
{
  CheckPolicyMessage msg = new CheckPolicyMessage();
  ...
  // set the msg properties in all of your case statements, note, you have 
  // one treated as an exception case (Policy Exist) but doesn't appear that you 
  // communicate it back to the user.
  msg.Code = "???";
  msg.Message = "Some message you want to display here";
  ...
  return msg;
}
```

And then in JavaScript using jQuery (though that is optional, obviously), I'd do:

```
function CheckPolicy() {
  var policyCheck = new Object();
  policyCheck["PolicyNumber"] = // grab Policy Number from page.
  policyCheck["PolicyMod"] = // grab Policy Mod from page.

  $.ajax({
    url: 'NameOfAspxPageWithCheckPolicyMethod.aspx/CheckPolicy',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(policyCheck),
    success: function (data) {
      // I *think* it'd be data.d.Message. When I've done it, I'm returning
      // lists so it is data.d[i].Whatever and iterating it in a for loop.
      // can use Chrome's Dev Tools (or others) to inspect the data element
      // at the next line and see what it contains (which tells you how to grab).
      // May be data.Message, not sure, but again, inspect data at this point.
      $('#IdOfSpanForlblresult').text(data.d.Message);
    },
    error: function (response) {
      // probably a similar thing, but you will want to communicate
      // how that it failed on the server end somehow. Possibly:
      // $('#IdOfSpanForlblresult').text(response.responseJSON.Message);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I ended up finding a much easier way to do it with the help of a friend. I simply added lblresult.Text = "Save Successful"; right before the conn.Close() at the bottom of SaveExceptionData.